# Autocomplete/suggest functionality in an applescript input box

Tags: applescript, applescript-objc

I am trying to build an applescript dialog that helps me keep track of the things I am working on.  To make it really effective I'd like to have it look up items from my todo list and suggest them as I type a la google suggest or other javascript autocomplete functionality.

I was thinking it would be fairly simple if I just captured the input of the @ key, which I wanted to use to denote project or the # key for tasks and at that point started matching the input to my list of tasks or projects.  For example, lets say I type:

"Worked on feature for @"

At this point the input of the @ would start capturing keyboard input and try to suggest one of the projects on my todo list. This is where I am stuck.  It seems like I should be able to attach a listener or something to my input box but I can't seem to find any examples or reference to such functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with applescript. You need to build your own window in a cocoa application and then hook into the NSTextField's methods to do this. It's not too difficult but it requires a whole different set of skills than applescript.

Comment: Thanks, that is sort of what I gathered from the examples or lack thereof.  I guess I'll have to go learn Cocoa now. :)

Comment: Any tutorial to suggest on this?